# PHP <<<OUT and OUT;

Tags: php

I saw this used as a replacement for quotes with multi-line text in the Glype php source code, and I want to learn more about it but the special symbols mean I can't google it. How exactly does this work?

Comment: Just do not use it for the HTML output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [`PHP heredoc syntax`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) :)

Heredoc is a robust way to create string in PHP with more lines but without using quotations. Heredoc is rarely used as the day by day usage is more complicated as creating strings with quotes or double quotes. Besides this the not properly used heredoc can lead to problems in your code.

---

> A third way to delimit strings is the
>   heredoc syntax: <<<. After this
>   operator, an identifier is provided,
>   then a newline. The string itself
>   follows, and then the same identifier
>   again to close the quotation.
>
> The closing identifier must begin in
>   the first column of the line. Also,
>   the identifier must follow the same
>   naming rules as any other label in
>   PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric
>   characters and underscores, and must
>   start with a non-digit character or
>   underscore.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate string delimiting style called [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).